# Gauss's (Divergence) theorem in Classical Electrodynamics

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, calculus

How does [divergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem) holds good for electric field.
How does this hold true-

$$\iiint\limits_{\mathcal{V}} (\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{E})\ \mbox{d}V=\mathop{{\int\!\!\!\!\!\int}\mkern-21mu \bigcirc}\limits_{\mathcal{S}}       {}\vec{E}\cdot\hat{n}\ \mbox{d}A$$

Comment: Would http://math.stackexchange.com/ be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 2):

For a formal proof of the divergence theorem in general, I refer you to any basic textbook that covers vector calculus (for instance, Adams' 'Calculus'). As for developing a physical intuition on why it applies in this context, see my answer to your previous question (which was essentially the same).

Comment: i meant the proof of gauss divergence theorem taking the vector as electric feild. ∫∫∫(divergence E)dV=∫∫E.dA

Comment: Like I said, I refer you to Adams' book (or any number of websites which will undoubtably be easily found through google), for the proof itself is very tedious and not that enlightening, and I will not bother to reproduce it in full right here.